# Black tab bar turns white when exporting from Xcode to iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbar

When running my app via the iPhone Simulator / Xcode, the tab bar color is black. However, when I moved the app onto my iPhone for testing, the tab bar turned white.  I looked for someone with a similar experience via Google / Stack Overflow, but I couldn't find any answers.

Any suggestions?

EDIT - My Tab Bar icons have a clear background. As i mentioned before the color is black in the simulator, but white on my phone.  Do i need to color in the background of my icons?

EDIT 2 - I actually went into Interface Builder and found out that the tabbar default color was white.  I still cant figure out why it showed up as black in the simulator but thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

When running in the iPhone Simulator, you are only "simulating" the style of the device's status bar. The simulated setting for this can be found in the Interface Builder portion of Xcode 4 or in Interface Builder.app bundled with Xcode3 – look for the "Simulated Metrics" section of the Attributes inspector when you have your UIViewController selected.

Since the setting in Interface Builder only simulates the status bar style, you need to set it explicitly in your application code. This is done with the `setStatusBarStyle:animated:` method of the `UIApplication` class:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque
                                            animated:NO];
```

See the [UIApplication Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html) page for more information.

Comment: There is a huge, gigantic, enormous difference between a **white TAB BAR** and a **grey STATUS BAR**.

Comment: True, Radek. anc1revv, were you asking about the color of a tab bar which typically appear along the bottom of the screen) or the device's status bar (the narrow bit at the top)?

Comment: First he talks about tabbar and not the statusbar, then if had to set the style of UI elements that had been designed in IB in code again because they were only "simulated" in the simulator - hey, this would make the whole XCode design process incl. IB pretty useless - proven by contradiction :-). All my status bars look on the device exactly the same way they look in IB and simulator.

Comment: I was referring to the tab bar at the bottom of the screen

Comment: May not answer the question exactly, but it helped me. Thanks!